# Quil loading an image to an already created applet

Tags: clojure, quil

I'm trying to create a load an image to applet using Clojure Quil library. When I'm storing the *load-image* reference and use it with `image` call, during the load it works. But when I do a load and show within draw it is not working.

**This works:**

```
(ns img-demo.core
  (:require [quil.core :as q]))

(def img (ref nil))

(def img-url "https://dummyimage.com/100x100/2c3e50/ffffff.png")

(defn setup []
  (q/background 0)
  (dosync (ref-set img (q/load-image img-url))))

(q/defsketch example
  :title "image demo"
  :setup setup
  :draw #(q/image @img 0 0)
  :size [600 600])
```

**This is not working,**

```
(ns img-demo.core
  (:require [quil.core :as q]))

(def img-url "https://dummyimage.com/100x100/2c3e50/ffffff.png")


(q/defsketch example
  :title "image demo"
  :draw #(q/image (q/load-image img-url) 0 0)
  :size [600 600])
```

In the later case, I understand that `load-image` should be called inside `quil.applet/with-applet`. Since it is happening inside `defsketch`, I expect that to be automatically taken care or at least throw an NPE. Why it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

`load-image` loads an image asynchronously, so the reason it's not working in your second example is because the image hasn't been loaded yet when `draw` gets called. You can check this by branching using the `loaded?` function before the call to `image`:

```
(q/defsketch example
             :title "image demo"
             :draw #(let [img (q/load-image img-url)]
                      (if (q/loaded? img)
                        (q/image img 0 0)
                        (q/ellipse 100 100 100 100)))
             :size [600 600])
```

Running the above code, you'll see a circle being drawn, since `img` hasn't been loaded yet. You don't get a Null Pointer Exception either, since `load-image` hasn't returned `nil` - it just didn't finish loading the image before `draw` was called. As such, all that happens is that nothing is drawn onto the blank canvas.

That's why it's usually recommended to load images in `setup` (and why your first example works). `setup` gets executed *before* `draw`, which guarantees that images will already be loaded when `draw` gets called.